# Flash FontWeight dosn't work in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, actionscript-3, flash, ubuntu

I have the following code:

```
var selectionFormat : TextLayoutFormat = new TextLayoutFormat();
selectionFormat.fontWeight = "bold"; // should it be FontWeight.BOLD?
```

And then I set this format to a FixedRichText, which makes it bold.

This works fine in Windows 7, but not in Ubuntu. Is the problem anyhow related to my way of setting the fontWeight with the hard-coded string "bold".

Didn't find any similar problems so any idea will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What font are you using?

Comment: Forgot to mention that - I am using Arial.